# Is there a tool to clean/vacuum the walls after hardwood was removed and installed?

Tags: vacuum

My walls are pure white and I am now seeing dust left after the hardwood was installed
What vacuum attachment do the pros use to clean walls like these ?

Comment: A damp cloth will work.  If you have a vacuum with a hose, maybe a soft brush attachment, but they are usually on the small side for walls.

Comment: Considering this https://www.amazon.ca/Cen-Tec-Systems-55871-Mophead-Microfiber/dp/B00DQKIDAU/ref=sr_1_9?keywords=wall+vacuum+attachment&qid=1664904544&qu=eyJxc2MiOiIwLjAwIiwicXNhIjoiMC4wMCIsInFzcCI6IjAuMDAifQ%3D%3D&sprefix=wall+vacuum+atta%2Caps%2C111&sr=8-9

Comment: Should work as well as a damp cloth.

Comment: Oh and elbow grease comes in handy.